# Как избавиться от 0 в статистике dle?

Tags: php, dle

Здравствуйте, есть вот такой хак. [Страница с хаком](http://cms-file.ru/all_for_dle/hack_for_dle/291-statistika-dlya-dle-proverenno-na-dle-95.html).

И в нем выводятся числа, сколько материалов добавлено сегодня (+3, +33, +0). Как сделать так, чтобы если сегодня каких-то материалов не было (+0), то 0 не показывался. Т.е. показывались цифры только в том случае, если материалов >0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

46 строка, замени на

```
$stats_day = $row['count'] ? $row['count'] : '';
```